# Is there an efficient way (not a for loop) to initialize an array in numpy where each cells is a multiple of the previous cell?

Tags: python, arrays, axis, numpy-ndarray

I would like to create a numpy array (in python), where the axes values are determined by the value in the previous cell and an additional function.

For example: 
In the following example the values on the y axis (rows) is determined by:

```
Array[i:0] = Array[i-1:0] + 3 + some_other_func()
```

And the values in the x axis (col) are determined by:

```
Array[0:i] = Array[0:i-1] + 4 + some_other_func()
```

[[ 0  4  8]

[ 3  0  0]

[ 6  0  0]

[ 9  0  0]]

The code I have now is as follows:

```
matrix = np.zeros((len(seq1) + 1, len(seq2) + 1))

for i in range(1, len(seq1) + 1):
        matrix[i][0] = matrix[i - 1][0] + get_pair_score(seq1[i - 1], GAP,
                                                         score_dict)
    for j in range(1, len(seq2) + 1):
        matrix[0][j] = matrix[0][j - 1] + get_pair_score(seq2[j - 1], GAP,
                                                             score_dict)
```

However, it's taking a very long time to run (my sequences are very long strings...) and I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

I know that I can fill a row or column using this syntax:

```
x[:,0] = some_value
x[0,:] = some_value
```

but I can't figure out a way to tell numpy to fill the cells in a similar manner when the value in one cell depends on the previous cell.

Any help or insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are [accumulator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) functions, specifically [cumsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) since you are summing the previous result to your current.

Let's write the equation for the first column where x[i] is the value at row i of the first column and function(i) is the function for ith row (i.e. `get_pair_score(seq1[i - 1], GAP, score_dict)`) then your column values can be written as:

```
x[i] = 0
x[i+1] = x[i] + function(i)
x[i+2] = x[i+1] + function(i+1)
....
x[n] = x[n] + function(n-1)
```

Now what you can do is expand the equations so you substitute the values with the equations above (e.g. replace x[i] in the second equation with 0 and replace x[i+1] in the third equation with the equation above and so on.)

```
x[i] = 0
x[i+1] = x[i] + function(i) = 0 + function(i)
x[i+2] = x[i+1] + function(i+1) = (x[i] + function(i)) + function(i+1) = (0 + function(i)) + function(i+1)
....
x[n] = 0 + function(i) + function(i+1) + function(n-2) + function(n-1)
```

Here we see that x[a] is essentially the cumsum of function from 0 to a
so x is just cumsum([function(i) for i in range(n)])

and in your case it should be something like:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

def random_func(seq1_i):
    return seq1_i ** 2

seq1 = randint(0, 10, size=10)
seq2 = randint(0, 10, size=15)
x = np.zeros((len(seq1)+1, len(seq2)+1))
x[1:,0] = np.cumsum([random_func(seq1[i]) for i in range(len(seq1))])
x[0,1:] = np.cumsum([random_func(seq2[i]) for i in range(len(seq2))])
```

where random_func(x) would be `get_pair_score(x, GAP, score_dict)` in your case.
This would be more efficient if you can vectorize get_pair_score() operation so you can just do np.cumsum(get_pair_list)

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, when using your code I'm getting an error "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1948) into shape (1949)". I'm not sure why this would be, since I haven't changed the size or shape of the matrix...

Comment: sorry fixed the problem. made a working sample example.

Comment: The problem was matrix is `len(seq1) + 1` long so you should only do `x[1:,0] = some_values`